# Boring SSL Handshake Failure and Error copying Identity Cred

Tags: ios, ssl, alamofire, handshake, boringssl

I am trying to use Self Signed certificate for my request through Alamofire.

> let trustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(certificates:
>   [certificate], validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true)
>
> ```
>                 let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
>                     "https:-domain-name": trustPolicy,"domain-name" : .disableEvaluation]
>                 let policyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
> ```

But I am getting following error.

> CredStore - copyIdentPrefs - Error copying Identity cred. 
>   Error=-25300, query={
>       class = idnt;
>       labl = "https://domain-name:443/";
>       "r_Ref" = 1; }

and

> > [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724)
> >     [C1.1:2][0x139d1bd20] Alert level: fatal, description: handshake
> >     failure   2019-01-22 15:34:23.448605+0530 DB[1276:264543]
> >     [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C1.1:2][0x139d1bd20]
> >     [boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation
> >     failed within the library
>
> 2019-01-22 15:34:23.448796+0530
>
> > DB[1276:264543] [BoringSSL]
> >     boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205) [C1.1:2][0x139d1bd20]
> >     5266093016:error:10000410:SSL
> >     routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.230.1/ssl/tls_record.cc:586:SSL
> >     alert number 40
>
> 2019-01-22 15:34:23.448986+0530 DB[1276:264543]
>
> > [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3545)
> >     [C1.1:2][0x139d1bd20] SSL_AD_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
>
> 2019-01-22
>
> > 15:34:23.464957+0530 DB[1276:264543] TIC Read Status
> >     [1:0x281599800]: 1:-9824
>
> 2019-01-22 15:34:23.467598+0530
>
> > DB[1276:264543] Task <43E199F9-B030-4BFD-B9E0-8C9F59B43E72>.<1>
> >     HTTP load failed (error code: -9824 [1:-9824])
>
> 2019-01-22
>
> > 15:34:23.468019+0530 DB[1276:264574] Task
> >     <43E199F9-B030-4BFD-B9E0-8C9F59B43E72>.<1> finished with error - code:
> >     -9824 2019-01-22 15:34:23.470149+0530 DB[1276:264574] Task <43E199F9-B030-4BFD-B9E0-8C9F59B43E72>.<1> load failed with error
> >     Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-9824 "Unknown error: -9824"
> >     UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask
> >     <43E199F9-B030-4BFD-B9E0-8C9F59B43E72>.<1>,
> >     _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
> >     0x100201bb03106e120000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824,
> >     _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> >         "LocalDataTask <43E199F9-B030-4BFD-B9E0-8C9F59B43E72>.<1>" )} [-9824]

Have been trying this from past 1 week. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would maybe help to format your question a little bit better.

Comment: Curious if you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling evaluation in Alamofire doesn't disable the system's base verification of certificates which blocks self-signed certificates by default. I suggest you read [Apple's ATS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/NSAppTransportSecurity), but I'm guessing this will require some combination of `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` for your domain and other settings. You should also make sure not to ship those settings if you can help it.